# Black Screen After Suspend, Lenovo Thinkbook

Tags: 20.04, suspend, screen

I have Thinkbook G2 ARE with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS after update my bios from facn26ww to facn27ww, i have a problem after suspend or close laptop,i have a blackscreen but the sound working,i listen for example spotify or youtube.

facn27ww changelog:
General Information:
FACN27WW

1. Enable Kernel DMA Protection.
2. Support SPD table for Hynix 8G and Micron 8G.
3. Adjust AUO panel brightness 60nits setting.

I read online there are a problem with "Kernel DMA Protection" but i don't know and i don't found a solution

This is kernel log before that i update bios, when suspend working

https://pastebin.com/t3MwnpGq

This is now

https://pastebin.com/Sk8DUbpM

Comment: Ok i solved with flashing bios previous version. Activate Rollback Bios option in bios menu. If someone need facn26ww i upload in my drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YhgDe1v4SLDqjzelKWGCahiJaGM2hERC/view?usp=sharing